# VLC player not installing on 17.10 ubuntu artful

Tags: dependencies, vlc

I have tried every option I could find @askubuntu - adding repository manually, command line installation, checked settings universe etc., -- I am still told the software has unmet dependencies, which I tried resolving one by one without success.
similar problem described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411518/what-is-the-root-cause-of-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-p/411530#411530

following screenshot with missing dependencies list included.
would love resolution I can actually follow (kiddie level ubuntu:)[image]

Comment: Can you please paste what the output of `apt-cache policy vlc` says?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved -
thanks to kind m-hampl at launchpad.net/ubuntu - link and solution as follows:

### https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/662308

ran command:

dpkg -l | grep vlc

then:
Uninstalling vlc-plugin-base (and any other vlc packages with version 3.0.0* listed in the output of that command) - according to the output in my case I ran the following command repeatedly with each package:

sudo apt-get purge vlc-plugin-base

as well purging the following packages:

libvlc-bin:amd64

libvlc5:amd64

libvlccore8:amd64

vlc-data

then installed vlc through ubuntu software app --  now again working fantastically, both with video files as well as dvd media.